# Why is my sql code throwing errors

Tags: sql-server, error-handling

Here's the concept: when a user selects a user list from the frontend treeview and clicks the `Save` button, the table which contains the mapping for role to users must clear itself of all the users with the role and re insert records with the given role id and userlist.

I am using following stored procedure and function:

Stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[AssignRoleToUser]
    @RoleID INT = 0,
    @UserID varchar(max) = ''
AS
BEGIN
   delete from UserRole 
   where RoleID = @RoleID 
     AND UserID IN (SELECT UserID FROM UserRole)

   INSERT INTO UserRole(UserID, RoleId) 
      SELECT id, @RoleID 
      FROM dbo.CSVToTable(@UserID)
END
```

Function

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[CSVToTable] (@InStr VARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS @TempTab TABLE (id int not null)
AS
BEGIN
    ;-- Ensure input ends with comma
    SET @InStr = REPLACE(@InStr + ',', ',,', ',')

    DECLARE @SP INT
    DECLARE @VALUE VARCHAR(1000)

    WHILE PATINDEX('%,%', @INSTR ) <> 0 
    BEGIN
       SELECT  @SP = PATINDEX('%,%',@INSTR)
       SELECT  @VALUE = LEFT(@INSTR , @SP - 1)
       SELECT  @INSTR = STUFF(@INSTR, 1, @SP, '')

       INSERT INTO @TempTab(id) VALUES (@VALUE)
    END

    RETURN
END
```

But I get this error

> Msg 217, Level 16, State 1, Procedure AssignRoleToUser, Line 7
>   Maximum stored procedure, function, trigger, or view nesting level exceeded (limit 32).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error is exactly saying what went wrong as below, along with the line number.

```
Msg 217, Level 16, State 1, Procedure AssignRoleToUser, Line 7
```

Take out the line 7 from your procedure `AssignRoleToUser`

```
INSERT INTO UserRole(UserID, RoleId) SELECT id, @RoleID 
FROM  dbo.CSVToTable(@UserID)
```

As can be seen, it's calling another function named `dbo.CSVToTable`. Likewise `dbo.CSVToTable` may be calling some other procedure\function and that's how the nesting depth has reached to maximum limit. so the error is.

Also, In Line 6 in your procedure `AND UserID IN (Select UserID from UserRole)` is not needed. which makes it as below

```
delete from UserRole where RoleID = @RoleID
```

You can run the below query which will list out all procedure that gets called in chain when running `AssignRoleToUser` procedure (Query observed from [Get All Nested Stored Procedures](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/487419/SQL-Server-Scripts-Get-All-Nest))

```
SELECT  * FROM 
(SELECT  NAME AS ProcedureName, SUBSTRING(( SELECT  ', ' + OBJDEP.NAME
FROM    sysdepends
        INNER JOIN sys.objects OBJ ON sysdepends.ID = OBJ.OBJECT_ID
        INNER JOIN sys.objects OBJDEP ON sysdepends.DEPID = OBJDEP.OBJECT_ID
WHERE obj.type = 'P'
AND Objdep.type = 'P'
AND sysdepends.id = procs.object_id
ORDER BY OBJ.name

FOR
XML PATH('')
), 2, 8000) AS NestedProcedures
FROM sys.procedures  procs )InnerTab
WHERE NestedProcedures IS NOT NULL
AND NAME = 'AssignRoleToUser'
```

Answer (score 0):

The error says that you have a call to a procedure, function, or trigger which calls another one which calls another one, etc etc, until the call is 32 calls deep. At this point it's giving and saying 'too much!'.

Do you have any triggers on the UserRole table? Will they call other things? If so, what will they do? And so on...

Comment: No, I created a simple table with userid and roleid as columns and am calling it userrole, no trigggers nothing were defined. Also I populated the table with 54 users with 6 roles. so each role has 9 users. The table I created was for testing purpose. SO no triggers at all. I wonder if the function was nesting within but I could n't know how so I posted the question here. Can i check it with Sql Profiler. I am not very much used to it.